# server downtime solution?

Tags: dns, server, vps, backups, downtime

I am managing a few sensitive websites, that need to be up and running 24/7 how ever I worked with many VPS and dedicated server providers over the time.
The problem is that downtime is inevitable, at least for a few hours a year and my client is pinging the websites round the clock.

Is there any solution like automatic switching DNS or hosting on 2 servers from 2 different providers and is there a way for syncing the data between servers before actual sinking.

Comment: Have you considered a CDN like Amazon CloudFront or CloudFlare?

Comment: I am using NetDNA, however CDN only deals with pictures and js, css files.I have problem when the main server goes offline due to network problems. are Amazon CloudFront or CloudFlare any different from NetDNA.

Answer (score 2):

Use Scalr

> **Fault-tolerance, backups, uptime, and efficiency**
>
> Scalr provides you with a high uptime, fault-tolerant website: Scalr
>   monitors all your servers for crashes, and replaces any that fail. It
>   backups your data at regular intervals, and uses Amazon EBS for
>   database storage. And to make sure you never pay more than you should,
>   Scalr lowers costs by decommissioning servers when load subsides.

http://code.google.com/p/scalr/

The also have a hosted solution at http://scalr.net/